# In my servlet programming using with database.it is not giving any output but without JDBC or database it is running correctly.how can i fix it?

Tags: mysql, servlets

When i run a simple programme(without database) it run correctly but when i run my servlet programming with database it doesn't.I want to run my login page where registered user's data will be store in mySQl database .i am doing this programme in netbeans IDE 8.0.2 with mySQL database. the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <html>
<head><title>Registration form</title>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
       <body>
    <form action="Register" method="get">
        <p>Name:<input type="text" name="username"/></p><br/>
        <p>Password:<input type="password" name="password"/></p><br/>
        <p>EmailId:<input type="text" name="emailid"/></p><br/>
        <select name="usercountry">
            <option>India</option>
            <option>pakistan</option>
            <option>USA</option>
            <option>australia</option>
            <option>other</option>
        </select><br/>   <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="login"/>
       </form>
</body>
```

**Register.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;    
import java.sql.Connection;    
import java.sql.DriverManager;    
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;    
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 

@WebServlet(name="Register",urlPatterns={"/Register"})
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String n=request.getParameter("username");
            String p=request.getParameter("password");
            String e=request.getParameter("emailid");
            String c=request.getParameter("usercountry");
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registeruser","root","Mysql");
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into registeruser values(?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, n);
                ps.setString(2, p);
                ps.setString(3, e);
                ps.setString(4, c);
                int i=ps.executeUpdate();
                if(i>0)
                    out.print("you are successfully registered....");}
            catch(Exception e2){
                System.out.print(e2);
            }
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually your applicationserver (Tomcat or similar) will show you some more in the server logs. Have you added the JDBC driver for the database to the lib directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right , and only requirement is add mysql-connector.jar file in your lib folder .